# Is size limit of Bitbucket repository includes Branches and tags inside it?

Tags: bitbucket

As per my knowledge size limit of Bitbucket repository is as follows :
Soft Limit : 1 GB
Hard Limit : 2 GB

It might be silly asking but I want to confirm that does it include Branches and Tags inside that 2GB hard limit or they are not stored under repository space.

Answer (score 1):

Branches and tags are part of the 2GB limit. I think you might be confused about how they're stored on disk, though:

- Branches are composed of commits. The commits themselves are not duplicated on-disk, though, so anything common to multiple branches will still only be stored once.
- Tags are just special labels on specific commits, usually for human readability ("v1" instead of "1f91bdb7518af0645f3aea17cb0eecc2b3780747", for example), so the presence or absence of tags won't have any effect on disk usage.